# Hessian Matrix Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, hessian-matrix, elliptic-equations

Consider the linear elliptic operator of the form
$$Lu=a^{ij}D_{ij}u+b^iD_iu$$
with coefficient satisfying
$$\lambda I \leq [a^{ij}] \leq \lambda^{-1} I , \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, |b^i|\leq \mu$$
where the inequalities means, for instance, that the matrix $[a^{ij}]-\lambda I$ is semipositive define, and $\lambda,\mu$ are positive constants.

Let $u$ satisfying $Lu+f\geq0.$

Let $Q(x)\in O(n)$ (i.e., orthogonal matrices), such that
$$Q(x)^t(D^2u(x))Q(x)=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_k,-\lambda_{k+1},...,-\lambda_n)$$
where the $\lambda_i$ are positive and are the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix $D^2u$.

Set 
$$a_*(x)=Q(x)^t diag(\frac{1}{2}\lambda,...,\frac{1}{2}\lambda,2\lambda^{-1},...2\lambda^{-1})Q(x).$$
Show the following inequality:
$$\lambda/2|D^2u|\leq (a_*^{ij}-a^{ij})D_{ij}u$$

Comment: $D^2u(x)$ can have zero eigenvalues, also what is $D_{ij}$ in the desired inequality?

Comment: Sorry @daw I forgot an "u". It's $D_{ij}u$ and it is the $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$.